# Print All Paths in Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm pair class throws error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find the shortest path of the weighted graph in Android studio with the dijkstra algorithm. I want it to sort from the lowest weight to the largest using priority queue, but I get an error in the pair class. I can't use the getKey method. I would appreciate your help.
error:  int  key1 = p1.getKey();
int   key2 = p2.getKey();
Required type: int

public class printpath {

```
static class Edge {
    int source;
    int destination;
    int weight;

    public Edge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

static class Graph {
    int vertices;
    LinkedList<Edge>[] adjacencylist;

    Graph(int vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        adjacencylist = new LinkedList[vertices];
        //initialize adjacency lists for all the vertices
        for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
            adjacencylist[i] = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
        Edge edge = new Edge(source, destination, weight);
        adjacencylist[source].addFirst(edge);

        edge = new Edge(destination, source, weight);
        adjacencylist[destination].addFirst(edge); //for undirected graph
    }

    public void dijkstra_PrintPaths(int sourceVertex){

        boolean[] SPT = new boolean[vertices];
        //distance used to store the distance of vertex from a source
        int [] distance = new int[vertices];

        int [] parentVertex = new int[vertices];

        //parent of the source vertex will be -1
        parentVertex[0] = -1;

        //Initialize all the distance to infinity
        for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
            distance[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        //Initialize priority queue
        //override the comparator to do the sorting based keys
        PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(vertices, new Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Pair<Integer,Integer> p1, Pair<Integer,Integer> p2) {
                //sort using distance values
                int  key1 = p1.getKey();
               int   key2 = p2.getKey();
                return key1-key2;
            }
        });
        //create the pair for for the first index, 0 distance 0 index
        distance[0] = 0;
        Pair<Integer, Integer> p0 = new Pair<>(distance[0],0);
        //add it to pq
        pq.offer(p0);

        //while priority queue is not empty
        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            //extract the min
            Pair<Integer, Integer> extractedPair = pq.poll();

            //extracted vertex
          int    extractedVertex = extractedPair.getValue();
            if(SPT[extractedVertex]==false) {
                SPT[extractedVertex] = true;

                //iterate through all the adjacent vertices and update the keys
                LinkedList<Edge> list = adjacencylist[extractedVertex];
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    Edge edge = list.get(i);
                    int destination = edge.destination;
                    //only if edge destination is not present in mst
                    if (SPT[destination] == false) {
                        ///check if distance needs an update or not
                        //means check total weight from source to vertex_V is less than
                        //the current distance value, if yes then update the distance
                        int newKey =  distance[extractedVertex] + edge.weight ;
                        int currentKey = distance[destination];
                        if(currentKey>newKey){
                            Pair<Integer, Integer> p = new Pair<>(newKey, destination);
                            pq.offer(p);
                            distance[destination] = newKey;
                            parentVertex[destination] = extractedVertex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //print Shortest Path Tree
        printDijkstra(parentVertex, distance, sourceVertex);
    }

    public void printDijkstra(int[] parent, int [] distance, int sourceVertex){
        System.out.println("Dijkstra Algorithm: (With all paths)");
        for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + sourceVertex + "--> " +   + i + ": distance="+distance[i] + "  Path : ");
            printPathUtil(parent, i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void printPathUtil(int parent[], int destination){
        //if vertex is source then stop recursion
        if(parent[destination] == -1) {
            System.out.print("0 ");
            return;
        }
        printPathUtil(parent, parent[destination]);
        System.out.print(destination + " ");
    }

  
}
```

Comment: What is the import for the `Pair` class as, if I remember correctly, there is no `Pair` class in the java standard library.
Also, try typecastng to int `int  key1 = (int) p1.getKey();`

Comment: then how should I compare when making priority queue in java

Comment: how import javafx.util.pair  android project